# Fragment caching with Touch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, fragment-caching

Currently I am using fragment caching with an object key. And I expire the cache using Touch with updates the updated_at column and then the current cache become obsolete. And a new cache is generated the next time.

```
<% cache do product %>
```

The cache key for an object looks like this

```
table_name/ID-updated_at
```

Now I want to cache my products somewhere else. To do so I would like to do same thing as before which is simply give the object in cache options, but I can't do that :(

It would be great if I could generate a key like this in order to still have my cache expired with the Touch.

```
table_name/ID-something_updated_at
<% cache product,something do %>
```

Unfortunately this is not possible, does someone has any idea how I could solve my problem?

Greg

Answer (score 1):

You can pass any old array you like to the fragment, so it's a pretty simple change to achieve what you're after:

```
<% cache [product, other, product.updated_at] do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```